# Is there a way to make overlay objects non-clickable?

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm working on this project of mine that requires to define lat/lng elements by clicking and finally found a way to do so, but just discovered, that the already predefined elements interfere with the new overlay elements defining by the source below. So I looked and looked, and searched, and googled, but wasn't able to find any helpful info about that: is there a way to make the google maps overlays non-clickable?

I'm using a custom function to get the latitude and longitude of a click event and place a predefined circle overlay object. However if I have already predefined overlay elements, I cannot click on top of them to set a new overlay element. I.e. I'd need either to make them non-interactable or non-clickable, or just to set them on a different layer, so that they don't interfere with the click events for the new elements.

Here's the JS I use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var map;
    var markersArray = []; //the array for the newly defined objects

    function initMap()
    {
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41, 29);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        // add a click event handler to the map object
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(event)
        {
            // place a marker
            placeMarker(event.latLng);

        });

            // I've predefined a couple of markers just to see how it works with already defined elements and discovered this interference that I mentioned above   
        var mar1 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.9653, 29.3705);
        var marker1 = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: mar1,
        radius: 2500,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
        });
        var mar2 = new google.maps.LatLng(40.9664, 29.3252);
        var marker2 = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: mar2,
        radius: 2500,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        map: map
        });
    marker1.setMap(map);
    marker2.setMap(map);

    }

    function placeMarker(location) {
        // first remove all new markers if there are any, so that we define one new at a time
        deleteOverlays();

        var new_marker = new google.maps.Circle({
            center: location,
            radius: 2500,
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 0,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            //position: location, 
            map: map
        });

        // add marker in markers array
        markersArray.push(new_marker);

    }

    // Deletes all markers in the array by removing references to them
    function deleteOverlays() {
        if (markersArray) {
            for (i in markersArray) {
                markersArray[i].setMap(null);
            }
        markersArray.length = 0;
        }
    }

</script>
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tCcLR/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set [{clickable: false} in the CircleOptions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#CircleOptions).

```
    var new_marker = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: location,
        radius: 2500,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 0.8,
        strokeWeight: 0,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 0.35,
        clickable: false,     // <=====================
        map: map
    });
```

<kbd>[Modified jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ulysse_bn/n5rh4azv/)</kbd>